# How to bind a progressbar to a task?

Tags: java, android, xml, progress-bar

when I press on a Button in my App, I am directed to a new Activity, but this takes a little time and the user might think the App is idle. So I want to have a progressbar or this little circle spinning while the new Activity is loading. The question now, how can I set such a progressbar to the Intent task, so that it fills accordingly to the loading progress?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably put this in the the "on create view" method and do it manually. But maybe there's a nicer way of doing this using a tool/lib

Comment: try this [swipeToRefresh](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html)

Comment: The problem is, when changing activity the view will get destroyed and a new one created. You should specify better what's your real use case here, your question is vague.

Comment: So when I press the Button, nothing is happening for a few seconds. Meaning the View with the Button is still active. Then after like 7 seconds, the new activity appears and is fully useable,

Answer (score 1):

You can give some predefined delay and use any of the UI elements like I used alert dialog for my application, you can use any other element and set the timer appropriately.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setMessage("Please wait you are being redirected");

                final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();

                alert.show();
                alert.setCancelable(false);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MyAccount.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        if (alert.isShowing()) {
                            alert.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }, 3000);
```